# How to write precondition in pseudo code

Tags: c#, java, mysql, pseudocode, preconditions

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to represent a pre-condition in pseudo code as I have had a look around can not find anything on the subject.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo-code, is, *by definition*, not formalized code. An example of using pseudo-code to define a precondition for a C# method would be:

```
// Precondition: Object must have been initialized by calling init() or by
// manually setting properties X and Y such that X.Foo >= Y.Bar.
public void doUsefulWork() {
    ...
}
```

Clearly, since pseudo-code is not formalized, it cannot be verified by the compiler.

- It's the duty of the *user* of the method to ensure that the preconditions are met, and
- it's the duty of the *developer* of the method to acknowledge that changing the precondition is (usually) a breaking change.

Answer (score 3):

I see here two possibilities:

1. If you can formulate your conditions into real code, I would give [Programming With Assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) a try (or the .NET equivalent [Debug.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). This way you can actually let the your conditions be checked during run time with `assert condition`
2. If this is not the case or you simply don't want to, you could write the pre- and post condition into your JavaDoc.

   ```
   /**
    * @precondition: the connection has been established.
    * 
    * @postcondition: the schema is created.
    * 
    */
   ```

You could even define these [JavaDoc annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) so they appear in the JavaDoc-generated documentation. This way you can use natural language you define what you want to assert.

You could also express your pre- and postconditions more mathematically I order to increase the succinctness of your conditions, which might make them more understandable:

For simple number comparisons you can surely use `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, etc. But let's say you want to define the invariant for a `Set` then you could express it as:

```
/**
  * @invariant: set == filterDuplicates(set)
  *
  */
```

Thus making use of hypothetical/pseudo functions to express your conditions.

This can be developed even further if you are fond of functional languages. My data structure and algorithms professor used **Haskell** to define precondition, postcondition and invariants for newly introduced data structures:

```
module TreeSets(TreeSet, 
                contains, add, remove, card, traverse)
where
data Ord t => TreeSet t = E | N (TreeSet t) t (TreeSet t)

inv E = True
inv(N l x r) = all(<x)(abs l) && all(>x)(abs r) &&
   inv l && inv r
```

It really depends for whom you are writing this, hence my recommendation is to use **natural language**. It can be understood by everyone and is especially for object-oriented programs the easiest to formulate.